# Using gMSA along with PsExec

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, psexec

I am launching an executable using PsExec, the username being passed to PsExec corresponds to a gMSA account.

1. Can an executable launched using PsExec get password updated when it's rotated automatically in the AD domain controller? I know password will be automatically updated in the client for windows services, want to check if this is the same for executable's launched using PsExec.
2. How to verify that the Client executable has refreshed the password when it's changed in the domain controller? Any logs I could look into? I know I can check for PasswordLastSet in Server, but want to verify that client using gMSA account got the new password.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [GetServiceAccountPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secmgmt/getserviceaccountpassword) function have some more background on this.

But in short, you don't have to worry about any of the password business.

Quote from the above link:

*The operating system first attempts to retrieve the password from the local cache if it is not time to fetch the password. If it is time to fetch the password, then the operating system contacts the domain controller, otherwise, return any cached passwords with a status value of success.*

So based on these

1) yes but it's not getting the password directly, but it happens under the hood via calls into SSPI

2) no need to worry about this. It's all implemented at the LSASS layer.